# ¿Por qué mi tarea muere cuando mi tarjeta gráfica tiene menos del 2% de uso de memoria?

Tags: python-3.x, manejo-de-memoria, out-of-memory-error, cuda, gpu

Estoy executando un codigo utilisando GPU

```
...
self.device = torch.device("cuda:2" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
...
```

Pero cualquier sea el numero que utiliso conseguí que el proceso informático muriera:

```
(dee_env) jovyan@jupyter:~/use-cases/Scene_understanding/Code_Woodscape/deeplab_v3+$ python test_shap.py 
Killed
```

En efecto, con dmesg podemos ver que se fue arestado:

```
[3021444.187035] [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
[3021444.187037] [3676666]  1000 3676666      628      139    49152        0           977 tini
[3021444.187039] [3676699]  1000 3676699   103214    27447   319488        0           977 jupyter-labhub
[3021444.187040] [3677140]  1000 3677140     1838     1054    49152        0           977 bash
[3021444.187041] [3692544]  1000 3692544   186572    14572   253952        0           977 python
[3021444.187045] [3692547]  1000 3692547   186572    14642   258048        0           977 python
[3021444.187048] [3693581]  1000 3693581 11478116   290622  5623808        0           977 python
[3021444.187077] [3693599]  1000 3693599   186572    14586   253952        0           977 python
[3021444.187092] [3705269]  1000 3705269 428018065 10181291 85082112        0           977 python
[3021444.187093] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_MEMCG,nodemask=(null),cpuset=cri-containerd-5a2221aa1c955ab36484d2ae7a54786ee39d111d1fad51eadf83d4a1dbc11809.scope,mems_allowed=0,oom_memcg=/kubepods.slice/kubepods-burstable.slice/kubepods-burstable-podf45aa152_d87b_4b7e_95bc_3572b29e506e.slice/cri-containerd-5a2221aa1c955ab36484d2ae7a54786ee39d111d1fad51eadf83d4a1dbc11809.scope,task_memcg=/kubepods.slice/kubepods-burstable.slice/kubepods-burstable-podf45aa152_d87b_4b7e_95bc_3572b29e506e.slice/cri-containerd-5a2221aa1c955ab36484d2ae7a54786ee39d111d1fad51eadf83d4a1dbc11809.scope,task=python,pid=3705269,uid=1000
[3021444.187660] Memory cgroup out of memory: Killed process 3705269 (python) total-vm:1712072260kB, anon-rss:40584944kB, file-rss:127932kB, shmem-rss:12288kB, UID:1000 pgtables:83088kB oom_score_adj:977
```

sin embargo parecia que habia memoria en los GPUs:

```
(dee_env) jovyan@jupyter:~/use-cases/_Scene_understanding/Code_Woodscape/deeplab_v3+$ nvidia-smiFri Sep  9 14:06:04 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01    Driver Version: 515.65.01    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100S-PCI...  On   | 00000000:00:06.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   42C    P0    38W / 250W |  32506MiB / 32768MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla V100S-PCI...  On   | 00000000:00:07.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   42C    P0    38W / 250W |  15512MiB / 32768MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Tesla V100S-PCI...  On   | 00000000:00:08.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   41C    P0    41W / 250W |    467MiB / 32768MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  Tesla V100S-PCI...  On   | 00000000:00:0B.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   45C    P0    52W / 250W |  22982MiB / 32768MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Si el OS revisa el oom_score y mata ese proceso, es porque definitivamente se quedó sin memoria disponible. Prueba usando `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` a ver si hay algo por ahí que pueda liberarse. De otra forma, no hay más camino que procesas lotes más pequeños de datos...

Comment: Intentar procesar un archivo de, por ejemplo 20 gb en una memoria de 8 gb es como intentar intentar meter un objeto de 1 metro cubico en una caja de 10 cm cubicos. No hay manera de que entre.